# do while with android button

Tags: android, android-button

Can you please help me some in this simple task? please see the attachment. you can do the task there.

I want to start a do-while loop by pressing a button to print some numbers, 
in the mean time the button will be ready for take next touch, (I mean one button will work for two task.)
in the next touch the button will stop to print those numbers.
if again I touch the same button then it will start print the numbers from the beginning.

Like: I press the button...its prining 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 then I press the button again then it stoped. then again I press the same button the its start to print 1,2,3...and so on.
means The process will run one the back of the interface.

I hope you can understand me.

can you please hep me on that?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work. No need for multithreading really.

```
  {
        Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private boolean running;
        myButton.setOnClickListener(this);        

}


        public void onClick(View v) {
        if(!running) {
           mHandler.post(numberPrinter);
    } else { 
           mHandler.removeCallBacks(numberPrinter);
           running = false;
    }
        }

    Runnable numberPrinter = new Runnable() {
          int i = 0;
        public void run(){
          running = true;
          System.out.println(i++);
          mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        };
```

Comment: You don't need the handler, you can use 'myButton.post()`

Comment: And this is multi-threading! Only that you are not creating the thread yourself.

Comment: @VikramBodicherla no... by default the Handler will use the looper on the main thread..

Answer (score 1):

hey u can do it with multi threading .

create a thread that will do printing . 
and on onClick event of button call the method that will call the Thread and Start and Stop the same.